# React SSR: Document is not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, material-ui, server-side-rendering

I have been working on this for two days now. Looked through multiple stack posts and still not found a suitable answer.

I am trying to rendering my react project in server like following:

**Server.js**

```
function handleRender(req,res){

  const sheetsRegistry = new SheetsRegistry();

  const sheetsManager = new Map();

  const theme = createMuiTheme({
    palette:{
      primary:green,
      accent: red,
      type: 'light',
    }
  })

  const generateClassName = createGenerateClassName();

  const html = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
    <JssProvider registry={sheetsRegistry} generateClassName={generateClassName}>
      <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme} sheetsManager={sheetsManager}>
        <TwoFA />
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    </JssProvider>
  )

  const css = sheetsRegistry.toString()

  res.send(renderFullPage(html,css))
}

function renderFullPage(html,css){
  return   `
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>2FA SDK</title>
      </head>
      <body style="margin:0">
        <div id="app">${html}</div>
        <script id="jss-server-side">${css}</script>
      </body>
    </html>
  `
}
```

**Client.js:**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import TwoFA from './App';
import {
    MuiThemeProvider,
    createMuiTheme,
    createGenerateClassName,
  } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import green from '@material-ui/core/colors/green';
import red from '@material-ui/core/colors/red';

class Main extends React.Component{
    componentDidMount() {
        const jssStyles = document.getElementById('jss-server-side');
        if (jssStyles && jssStyles.parentNode) {
          jssStyles.parentNode.removeChild(jssStyles);
        }
    }

    render(){
        return <TwoFA />
    }
}

const theme = createMuiTheme({
    palette: {
      primary: green,
      accent: red,
      type: 'light',
    },
  });

const generateClassName = createGenerateClassName();

if (typeof window !== 'undefined'){
    ReactDOM.hydrate(
        <JssProvider generateClassName={generateClassName}>
          <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
              <TwoFA/>
          </MuiThemeProvider>
        </JssProvider>,
        document.querySelector('#app'),
    );
}
```

**Webpack.config.js**

```
module.exports = [
    {
        /*Config for backend code*/ 
        entry: './src/server/server.js',
        output: {
            filename: 'server.js'
        },
        externals: [nodeExternals()],
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                    exclude: /node_modules/,
                    use: {
                        loader: "babel-loader"
                    }
                },
                {
                    test: /\.html$/,
                    use: {
                        loader: "html-loader",
                        options: { minimize: true }
                    }
                },
                {
                    test: /\.css$/,
                    use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,"css-loader"]
                }
            ]
        },
        plugins: [
            new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
                template: "./public/index.html",
                filename:"./index.html"
            }),
            new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
                filename: "[name].css",
                chunkFilename:"[id].css"
            })
        ]
    },
    { 
        entry: './src/client.js',
        output: {
           filename: 'bundle.js',
        },
        module: {
           rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.js$/,
                    exclude: /node_modules/,
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                },
                {
                    test: /\.html$/,
                    use: {
                        loader: "html-loader",
                        options: { minimize: true }
                    }
                },
                {
                    test: /\.css$/,
                    use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,"css-loader"]
                }
            ],
        },
        plugins: [
            new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
                template: "./public/index.html",
                filename:"./index.html"
            }),
            new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
                filename: "[name].css",
                chunkFilename:"[id].css"
            })
        ]
    }
]
```

**What I have tried:** I search on SO and found that many posts suggesting put a condition check like so : `if (typeof window !== 'undefined')`. However, this does not solve the problem.

I also understood that the error is due to the fact that during SSR, server-side has no **document** project.

I have searched on github issue page and someone mentioned that he ran into the problem with webpack, but same project worked fine with browserify.

**What I need help with**: I am trying to solve this problem as it cause the app to break.

I am suspecting that there is something wrong with webpack. I am looking a fix for this

Comment: `MiniCssExtractPlugin` might have to be blamed

Answer (score 5):

If you are using react-hooks, you can create your custom useDocument hook:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

export const useDocument = () => {
  const [myDocument, setMyDocument] = useState(null)
   
  useEffect(() => {
    setMyDocument(document)
  }, [])

  return myDocument
}
```

in your component:

```
...
const doc = useDocument()
...

<SomeComponent
 ref={doc && doc.body}
 ...
/>
...
```

Answer (score 4):

This issue usually happens because when react is rendered on the server. It does not have a document or window object on the server side and those objects are only available on the browser.

Try to call the document functions in or after `componentDidMount`.

```
componentDidMount(){
  this.setState({documentLoaded:true});
}

someFunction(){
  const { documentLoaded } = this.state;
  if(documentLoaded){
     // LOGIC USING DOCUMENT OBJECT
  }
}
```